# XMLHttpRequest (XHR) for Jint

Tags: javascript, c#, xmlhttprequest, jint

I am working on a program (C# with .Net Core 3.1) that needs to be extended with javascript. These javascripts need to be able to send web requests.

Since I like the implementation of Jint (https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) very much, my choice fell on this Javascript implementation. Unfortunately, the XMLHttpRequest object is not supported out of the box. Before I do the implementation myself, I wanted to politely ask if anyone has seen such an implementation before and might be able to tell me where to find it.

Of course I could also create my own implementation with a different interface, but this would then no longer be compatible with external libraries.

With kind regards
vocaris