How to make http rest requests within Jint script
I have an applicaton that runs hundreds of javascripts with jint generaly. Some of this scripts hava now the need of making outside requests. Without Jint, I would just make a simple fetch(), get the response and use the response as I need.
    using System;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Jint;
    
 ExecuteScript(string script)
        {
            var engine = new Engine();

            engine.SetValue("body", script)

            
    
            
            // Execute the script
            await engine.Execute(script)
    }

Example of Script:
const userId = body?.properties?.customerCode;
let userDetails = fetch(`https://getUserDetails.com/${userId}`)
if (userDetails?.hasMoney)
{
do something
}else{
do nothing
}


This, perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/q/67942257/1427878 -> https://github.com/sebastienros/jint/issues/442
